# How to fix wrong expo typescript type import of FieldArray from formik

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, formik

I was developing a form in an expo app and encountered a TypeScript error where FieldArray component was being imported as type any.

How to resolve this issue correctly? Can I modify the include to resolve this? If so how? If not, is there another way to get around this?

I tried different things and these are my observations:

1. The import is working correctly in the normal expo 48 starter template without ts
2. The import does not work correctlt in the expo 48 typescript template
3. The import does not work in the new expo 49 starter template with tabs
4. The import does not work correctly even in a .js or .jsx file with typescript in the project

I think this is because of the include not working correctly in the tscongfig.json

This is what tsconfig.json looks like for the expo 49 template

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".expo/types/**/*.ts",
    "expo-env.d.ts"
  ]
}
```